# How to config post parameters in http:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

We have an case that retrieve orders from our customers system by using http post call, post request include username and password, and we can get order contents response then.

We want to call customer's service every 10 minutes,  and then process the response in our service activator, however, I don't know how to config username and password as post parameters in spring integration configuration, anyone can help?

my current configuration

```
  <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inChannel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000"></int:poller>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="inChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="outChannel"/>
    <http:outbound-gateway
            url="http://****/vendorServer/order"
            request-channel="inChannel" reply-channel="outChannel" http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</http:outbound-gateway>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="outChannel" ref="orderService"/>
```

how to config username and password as post parameters in above configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP POST method implies the `body`. The organic way to provide the body in Spring Integration is message `payload`. Therefore you should consider to build a `Map` payload with required properties before sending to the `http:outbound-Gateway`